# Mapping from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of patients, e.g.:

[image]

and a dataset of diseases of each patient (by ICD code):

[image]

How can I flag each patient if he had history of a specific ICD code, desired output:

[image]

I am currently doing it with iteration but this takes too long....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need indicators - it means only `0, 1` values use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df1 = df1.join(pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('patient_id')['ICD']).max(level=0), on='patient_id')
```

If need counts `ICD` use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df2 = df1.join(pd.crosstab(df['patient_id'], df['ICD']), on='patient_id')
```

Difference is if duplicates in pairs `patient_id`, `ICD`.

Comment: Many thanks!!! How would you change the code with the get_dummies if 'ICD' is a string and not Numeric?

Comment: @gtomer - It should working same, for strings and also for numeric.

Comment: For string I got the following error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: @gtomer - there was bad `)`, need `).max(level=0)`

Comment: Indeed. I am grateful!!